# Export an excel Using Node.js and MySQL as database

Tags: mysql, node.js, excel, pipe, export

Is it possible to export an excel with more than 250k records and 21 columns in it. I have tried using fs, exceljs, and csv-writer but none of them worked. The approach which I am following right now - getting the data in chunks from the database to avoid Sequelize timeout error and then writing it into excel but sometimes this also results in javascript heap out of memory.

The Excel can also contain Marathi as well as English content.

Comment: This is too mush data in one time, maybe try to make your import by batch ? 

Eg : Start at line 0 -> read the next 1000 lines -> do the insert and save the last readed line // Start again but at the last readed line + 1

Comment: @Poutch I tried using it after 4-5 iterations it gives Sequelize Timeout Error because it is taking too much time in writing the excel.

Comment: The base questions has change no ? you have to do it by batch like i explain for an import case.

First try to open an exemple file (who looks like your final wanted one) and write something inside.


If it's working : Grab your data by batch (like 1000 lines) from the last saved id, save the last id, write this 1000 line at the end of your file, save & close the file, do it again until there is no more data to grab and write.